# Will JS remove dunamically created element with event listener if it's not connected to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, events, dom, garbage-collection, node-webkit

Let's imagine that we have a code like this:

```
function someName(callback) {
  var elem = document.createElement('input');
  elem.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
    callback();
  }, false);
  // some code
  elem.click();
}

// some code

someName(function() {
  alert("Hello world!");
});
```

The question is: will JS completely remove the "elem" element created in the "someName" function after moving out of it's callback's context? The other question is: will JS remove the "elem" element if it is not changed after emitting the "click" event?

Can you, please, explain me when the "elem" element will be removed?

P.S.: I'm trying to write a simple application with node-webkit and such kind of code is needed to let node-webkit open a file dialog (open file, save file and so on) and handle it's result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables defined inside a function only exist inside the function when the function is executed.

Your code creates an input element and it assigns a callback function to it's state change handler, but you don't actually attach/insert the element to the DOM anywhere, so the element only exists as that variable; it never becomes something in the DOM to exist after the function ends

Therefore when the function ends, the variable will be destroyed and that element wouldn't exist anymore, including the state change handler.

**sidenote**: it's `.createElement()` not `.create()` (unless you have code that defined a `.create()` method..)

Comment: This assumes that `callback` does not save `event.target` or `event.srcElement`, which are also references to the element. Note also that variables defined inside a function can outlive the function if they are captured by closures.

Comment: @RaymondChen well, yes, there are certainly plenty of ways to make it persist. But that wasn't really the question. The question was about what happens with the given code

Comment: @CrayonViolent, yes, you are right. It's really `createElement`, sorry )

Comment: So, does it mean that I can create a new input every time I access `someName` function and it will not pollute the environment? I'm asking about it because I'm not sure what will happen if the user clicks Cancel button (so, the event handler will not be called). If I perform any actions with the `callback` variable inside the `someName` function it doesn't affect on the scope of that input, does it?

Comment: @DWand How about instead of asking open-ended questions, you post the actual code for what you are wanting to do and then get some comments about it?

Comment: @DWand IOW it depends on what you're actually trying to do. I can say "yes" to your question as far as the code you posted, because of what I said in my answer. But that may not apply for what you are actually trying to do. There a ton of things you *could* do in both that function and the callback that could (intentional or not) cause the input field to stick around. And that may or may not be a bad thing, depending on what exactly you are trying to do. But again, rather than speculating on an open-ended question, just work out your code and then post it for comments

Comment: @CrayonViolent, okay. Thanks for help. Here is the code https://github.com/DWand/nw-fileDialog/blob/master/nw-fileDialog.js